# Update posts using knit2wp

Tags: r, wordpress, markdown, knitr

I have been able to successfully post to WordPress using knit2wp, even with images.

Even possessing such talent, I am not infallible. Indeed, even the above took some work.

I'd like to be able to update posts later.

Apparently, the RWordPress package allows for deletion of posts, but that doesn't help much if one cannot read the metadata of a post, delete it, post a new post, and update the metadata … and I do not offhand see an option or function to just update a post.

Any and all suggestions welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I also want to know the answer :) This is the reason that I do not like `knit2wp()` myself.

Comment: I'm looking at the code but unfortunately I'm not much of a coder

But if you can't solve it, who can?

Comment: I did not spend much time on it, and that does not mean the answer does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent version of knit2wp supports editing of posts. Case closed.

Comment: Does the RWordPress package still work for you? I keep getting the following error: ``Error: faultCode:  401  faultString:  Sorry, you are not allowed to publish posts on this site.``

Answer (score 1):

As you've alluded to, the RWordPress package in R does not support editing of posts.  RWordPress uses the XML-RPC interface to interface with Wordpress however, so you'd need to either:

1. Find another R package that does allow editing
2. Extend RWordPress to support the wp.editPost XML-RPC method.  This was only added in WP 3.4 which was released in June 2012.  RWordPress was last update August 2012 so it doesn't surprise me that it doesn't support it yet - perhaps the package has been abandoned?

You can read more about the WordPress XML-RPC methods in the WordPress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.editPost