# Error in xml.rpc(.server, method, as.character(blogid), names(login), : Problems

Tags: wordpress, knitr

```
> library(RWordPress)
> options(WordpressLogin = c(englianhu = 'mypassword'),
+         WordpressURL = 'http://user.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php')
> library(knitr)
> knit2wp('Natural Language Analysis.Rmd', title = 'Natural Language Analysis')
processing file: Natural Language Analysis.Rmd
output file: Natural Language Analysis.md
Error in xml.rpc(.server, method, as.character(blogid), names(login),  : 
  Problems
> traceback()
6: stop("Problems")
5: xml.rpc(.server, method, as.character(blogid), names(login), 
       as.character(login), content, as.logical(publish))
4: newPage(content, publish, blogid, login, "metaWeblog.newPost", 
       .server = .server)
3: newPost(content = list(description = "<p>This is an natural language 

analysis on the matching soccer teams&#39; name...
...
```

I tried to post by refer to [Update posts using knit2wp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614604/update-posts-using-knit2wp/29005797#29005797) and [Publish blog posts from R + knitr to WordPress](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/wordpress/) but faced above error, sounds unable read the username and password. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Wordpressurl has to be corrected, Wordpress.com uses https and user should be your username. 
Given your username the correct options should be something like:

```
options(WordpressLogin = c(englianhu = 'mypassword'),
        WordpressURL = 'https://englianhu.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php')
```

Comment: Its work, thanks lot, just wondering why the outcome of [Natural Language Analysis with R](https://englianhu.wordpress.com/2015/12/17/natural-language-analysis-with-r/) is not same as expected.

Comment: This does not work for me (my website does not use https).